# Is it possible to add listener to xAxis in App Designer

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to add a listener to the x Axis for a plot in a GUI. However, nothing I have tried seem to be working. The purpose for doing this is to update a max, min and mean field every time the viewing window changes.

Some things that I have tried:

```
addlistener(app.UIAxes.XLim, 'PostSet', @xChangeCallBack)
listener(app.UIAxes.XLim, 'PostSet', @xChangeCallBack)
```

.. and many other,

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you working with?

Comment: MATLAB R2018b student version